# c++ multithreading and mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm kind of familiar with C/Linux multithreading but this time I have to do some work with C++ on Windows but I couldn't get the hang of it. In my program, I have 2 functions which constantly try to reach the same file to do some printing operations and what happens is one of them never works which makes me think that a function is never able to open the file because the other one can always be writing on it. How can I implement threads to make this work? The code is roughly this:

```
std:mutex mut;
    main(){
        while(1){
            //get mychar from user
            print1(mychar, "my.txt");
            print2();
        }
    }

print1(int i, char* file){
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "a");
    /*print operations
    ..
    .*/
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

void print2(){
    /*getting a string
    ...
    Sleep(200);
    getting another string
    ...*/
    char getX[];  //fill buffers with the strings accordingly
    char getY[]; //basically i want to know if the initial string has changed
    if(*getX != *getY){
        std::Lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mut);
        FILE *f = fopen("my.txt", "a");
        fprintf(f, "%s ", getY);
        fclose(f);
    }
    getX = NULL;
    getY = NULL;
}
```

Comment: What is the `a` here: `FILE *f=fopen("my.txt",a);` ?

Comment: oh, I meant `"a"` for append mode. I will edit right away

Comment: why is there no mutex in print1? and I believe you have to do the fopen also in the guarded region

Comment: So to clarify, both `print1` and `print2` write to the file?

Comment: This program doesn't have multithreading -- so mutexes are not needed here. Also, mutex is local vairable in `main()` so it is not acessible by `print2()` (unless you pass reference, but you don't do that). Also, mixing C++11 and C-style files is bad.

Comment: If you want to wait until something happens in f, I think you have to resume to select(...)

Comment: Yes. Although print1 keeps printing as long as I give input, print2 may not always be printing.

Comment: @myaut I was guessing that I would need different threads to make this work concurrently though.

Comment: @myaut and I didn't quite understand threading in c++ which was my initial question. If I need multithreading and if yes, how can I implement it?

Comment: just because you know C doesn't mean you know C++.

Comment: Why are you unlocking the mutex? You have a lock_guard.

Comment: @Otomo I realized that seconds after but forgot to edit apparently. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that your mutex is declared locally in main. They need to be accessible to your functions. If everything relevant in your program is happening in this one file, then it's perfectly fine to use a globally declared mutex.

The second problem is that you're not locking either thread correctly. If you're going to be opening both files for appending, then the safest thing to do is to lock on open and unlock on close. You can accomplish this by initializing a lock guard using the global mutex on function entry:

```
std::mutex mut;

main(){
    while(1){
        //get mychar from user
        print1(mychar, "my.txt");
        print2();
    }
}

print1(int i, char* file){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mut);
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "a");
    /*print operations
    ..
    .*/
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

void print2(){
    /*getting a string
    ...
    Sleep(200);
    getting another string
    ...*/
    char getX[];  //fill buffers with the strings accordingly
    char getY[]; //basically i want to know if the initial string has changed
    if(*getX != *getY){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mut);
        FILE *f = fopen("my.txt", "a");
        fprintf(f, "%s ", getY);
        fclose(f);
    }
    getX = NULL;
    getY = NULL;
}
```

As someone else pointed out, you're not even using concurrency here. It's just one function call after the other. If you want to use threads, you can do this in your `while(1)` loop:

```
while(1){
    std::thread thread1(print1, mychar, "my.text");
    std::thread thread2(print2);
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```

*Edit*: I've edited your `print2` function to open the file only when it needs to write to it. This makes concurrency more sensible within the structure of your application.

Comment: `mychar` needs to be an integer or explicitly cast to one.

Comment: It compiled but I can't see any output from print2 and after multiple inputs to print1 the program starts to fall behind and I lose some inputs. `mychar` is of type `char`. I cast integer to char and that is my output. I am not interested in the integer value.

Comment: The problem is the line `if(*getX != *getY)`. This will return false every time because you initialize `getX` and `getY` without modifying them right before the conditional.

Comment: I tried initializing them globally as `char getX[256]; char getY[256];` and something like this in print2: `getX[256]=getText(something); getY[256]=getText(something);` and then put the conditional statement but it did not work

Comment: There's a logical error somewhere that I can't debug for you. You said before that running the functions sequentially didn't work, so I'm not surprised that they don't work when threaded. If you want to thread those two functions though, my answer does that for you. Aside from that, without more detail on what `getText(something)` does, there's nothing more I can do to help.